# How many permutations of 2 things, each appearing an arbitrary number of times in an arbitrarily sized set?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Say I have 3 A's and 2 B's, which make up a set of 5 numbers.

How many permutations are there of that set?

Doing it by hand, I can see that there are 10, but with my relatively limited math knowledge, I haven't really been able to see any obvious pattern when you change the numbers.

What's the formula that would tell me how many permutations there are?

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit the nCk formula does work for the most part unless you have, for example, 4 As and 1 B, in which case that still gives 10 even though there are only actually 5 permutations.  Another example would be 5 As and 0 Bs, which has 1 permutations but would still return 10 with nCk

Comment: If there are $a$ $A'$s and $b$ $B$'s then there will be $  ^{a+b} C_a $ ways. (Note that $ ^{a+b} C_a= ^{a+b} C_b$.)

Comment: @LeoRiesenbach:  No, the combination formula is correct.  $^5C_1=\frac {5!}{1!\cdot (5-1)!}=5$ and $^5C_0=1$

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

This is a simple question, and uses simple binomial calculation. However, it can be generalized. Here, I shall provide two possible solutions. Depending on the situation of the problem, as well as its complexity, you might choose to use which method.

## Solution 1

The number of ways to choose 3 out of 5 slots for the A's is $\binom {5}{3} =10$ ways

That is the answer to this problem.

The solution can be generalized as following:
Given a set of k character, consider the couple $(a_i,b_i)$ with $a_i$ refers to the character and $b_i$ represents the number of appearances.

Then, the answer is as follow:

### $ \binom{b_1+b_2+...b_k}{b_1} + \binom{b_2+b_3+...+b_k}{b_2} + ... + \binom{b_k}{b_k}$

### Solution 2

I first assume that the five characters given are different, then I have $5!=120$ ways to arrange them.

Now because the A's are the same, and the B's are the same, changing their situations does not matter. Therefore, the number of repetitions are: $3! \times 2! =12$

This means that actually, there are only: $ \frac{120}{12}=10$ ways to arrange the numbers.

The generalization is as following:

Denote the couples $(a_i,b_i)$ as in **solution 1**

Denote $S= \sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i$

The total number of solutions is:

### $ \frac{S!}{b_1! \times b_2! \times b_3! \times... \times b_k!}$

**Post script**: I left here two possibles solutions to this question, as it depends on the situation that you chooses to use which solution to the generalised problem